# How to determine speaker count in Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to discover if there is a way to determine how many channels are available for audio playback on an Android device. Whether it's 2 speakers on a tablet, or 5.1 through HDMI etc.

I've Google'd endlessly and I either can't ask the question in a Google friendly manor, or it's not possible. Nothing in AudioManager seems obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.